# Python running slower than MATLAB

Tags: performance, numpy, python-3.x, fft

I am translating a numerical method that I wrote in MATLAB to Python.  For some reason the Python code, which is almost identical, runs considerably slower.  Here `U` and `V` are the unknowns which are solved for at every timestep.  The size of `U[:,n]` and `V[:,n]` is 700x1.  The rest of the variables (`dt`, `A`, and `denom`) are constants.  Here is the loop (`numpy` has been imported as `*`):

```
for n in range(0, 400):
    UnVn2 = fft.fft(U[:, n] * V[:, n] ** 3)
    U[:, n +1 ] = fft.ifft((fft.fft(U[:, n]) / dt - UnVn2 + A) / denom)
    V[:, n + 1] = fft.ifft((fft.fft(V[:, n]) / dt + UnVn2) / denom)
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks greatly.

Comment: What python runtime?  Is it using a JIT compiler?  Are the BLAS and FFT routines as fast as the ones packaged with MatLab?  IIRC, MatLab uses [Intel](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl) and [AMD](http://developer.amd.com/tools/cpu-development/amd-core-math-library-acml/) binaries which are very heavily optimized.

Comment: I am still very new to Python, but I am running the code just by importing the file into IDLE.  Is that called JIT?  The Python runtime seems to be at least 3 times over MATLAB.  I had assumed that the numpy routines would be fully optimized since it is so commonly used for scientific computing.

Comment: `numpy` is capable of using those optimized routines.  See http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/numpyscipy-with-intel-mkl  But use the optimized library most appropriate for your processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how MatLab organizes the axes in multi-dimensional arrays, but I'm pretty sure numpy uses the C-like [row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) (edit: Wikipedia even mentions that MatLab uses column-major order ;) ).

Since you're operating on single columns only all your operations must iterate over rows. With row-major ordering this is generally less efficient than iterating over whole rows. Consider transposing the layout of your 2d arrays and you should get a noticeable increase in performance.

Answer (score 3):

See [this](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/numpyscipy-with-intel-mkl) for instructions on making python and numpy use the same accelerated FFT routines that ship with MATLAB.

If you have an AMD processor, see [these](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/740) instructions instead.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure of why Python is slower than Matlab, but...

The FFT, as a fourier transform, has a number of [properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Properties_of_the_Fourier_transform), which yield most (all) of your FFT operations unnecessary:

```
def func1(U, V, dt, denom, A) :
    UnVn2 = np.fft.fft(U * V**3)
    U_ = np.fft.ifft((np.fft.fft(U) / dt - UnVn2 + A) / denom)
    V_ = np.fft.ifft((np.fft.fft(V) / dt + UnVn2) / denom)
    return np.vstack((U_, V_))

def func2(U, V, dt, denom, A) :
    UnVn2 = U * V**3
    U_ = (U / dt - UnVn2) / denom
    U_[0] += A / denom
    V_ = (V / dt + UnVn2) / denom
    return np.vstack((U_, V_))

U = np.random.rand(700)
V = np.random.rand(700)
dt, denom, A = tuple(np.random.rand(3))

>>> func1(U, V, dt, denom, A)
array([[ 2.35201751 -1.11022302e-16j,  0.81099082 -2.45463372e-16j,
         0.48451858 +2.15658782e-18j, ...,  2.23237712 -5.24753851e-16j,
         1.15264205 -2.31140087e-16j,  1.06670009 +1.28369537e-16j],
       [ 2.89314136 +8.67361738e-17j,  3.65612404 -7.80625564e-17j,
         3.31383830 +8.96916836e-17j, ...,  0.90415910 +6.27969898e-16j,
         3.03505664 +4.72358723e-16j,  0.64669863 +4.99600361e-16j]])
>>> func2(U, V, dt, denom, A)
array([[ 2.35201751,  0.81099082,  0.48451858, ...,  2.23237712,
         1.15264205,  1.06670009],
       [ 2.89314136,  3.65612404,  3.3138383 , ...,  0.9041591 ,
         3.03505664,  0.64669863]])
>>> np.max(np.abs(func1(U, V, dt, denom, A) - func2(U, V, dt, denom, A)))
1.5151595604785605e-15
```

And of course:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('func1(U, V, dt, denom, A)', 'from __main__ import func1, U, V, dt, denom, A', number=400)
0.14169366197616284
>>> timeit.timeit('func2(U, V, dt, denom, A)', 'from __main__ import func2, U, V, dt, denom, A', number=400)
0.06098524703428154
```

Which I have to admit is less than I was expecting, but it is still almost 3x faster.

**EDIT**
The speed from not doing FFTs seemed too small, so I modified `func1` and `func2` to return a tuple with `(U_, V_)` and run the following code:

```
from time import clock
U = np.zeros((700,400), dtype=np.float)
V = np.zeros((700,400), dtype=np.float)
U[:,0] = np.random.rand(700)
V[:,0] = np.random.rand(700)
dt, denom, A = tuple(np.random.rand(3))
t = clock()
for j in xrange(399) :
    U[:, j+1], V[:, j+1] = func1(U[:, j], V[:, j], dt, denom, A)
print clock() - t
t = clock()
for j in xrange(399) :
    U[:, j+1], V[:, j+1] = func2(U[:, j], V[:, j], dt, denom, A)
print clock() - t
```

The printed output was `11.5148652438` and `0.321673111194` so the speed-up in the actual problem setting is more like x30.

I also timed pwuertz's proposal, with no significant improvement, `11.1805414552` and `0.297830755317` for the following code:

```
U = np.zeros((400, 700), dtype=np.float)
V = np.zeros((400, 700), dtype=np.float)
U[0] = np.random.rand(700)
V[0] = np.random.rand(700)
dt, denom, A = tuple(np.random.rand(3))
t = clock()
for j in xrange(399) :
    U[j+1], V[j+1] = func1(U[j], V[j], dt, denom, A)
print clock() - t
t = clock()
for j in xrange(399) :
    U[j+1], V[j+1] = func2(U[j], V[j], dt, denom, A)
print clock() - t
```

It does look much, much neater, though.

Comment: Getting rid of the fft is certainly a big improvement. The impact of memory alignment however depends on the size of the array and the hardware. On my system I'm seeing an improvement of ~30% when switching the axes, and a factor of 2 for larger arrays (2000x2000). It's just a general advise to keep things like this in mind ;)